# How do I create a toolbar for the Taskbar on Windows?

Tags: .net, windows, taskbar

How do I go about creating my own taskbar toolbar, a la Windows Media Player:

[Windows Media Player's Start bar toolbar http://me.monoxide.ws/images/wmp-toolbar.gif](http://me.monoxide.ws/images/wmp-toolbar.gif)

Examples or documentation or even open source software that implements this for just about any language would be appreciated, but Google isn't being very helpful. Ultimately, I would like to do this in C# (I expect to need P/Invoke) for XP onwards, but any language and Vista onwards would be acceptable/helpful too.

Comment: I'm wondering why no one asked this question before....

Comment: To be honest, perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places, but it doesn't seem like they are used very much at all. The only other example I can think of besides WMP are desktop search applications like Google Desktop Search.

Comment: Imagine a taskbar with over 50 of those things

Comment: You mean like my system tray, only more annoying? This is why they can be explicitly hidden by the user I suppose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this out:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/e180c4d5-8cd7-47e3-b45a-d643c02bab36

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb776819.desk1%28en-us,VS.85%29.jpg))</sub>

> It's called as "Desk Band"
>
> See MSDN desription about this
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/shellcc/platform/shell/programmersguide/shell_adv/bands.asp
>   and sample over there
>   http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/dotnetbandobjects.asp

By the way, thanks for asking this question. Back in the days I also wanted to do this. However, yesterday I said bye bye to Windows and Hi to Mac. If you asked this yesterday I would upvote it trice if I could ;-)

Comment: For the record, the CodeProject project referenced is done in .NET 1.1, but the main solution and sample solution both cleanly upgraded to 2.0 (in VS2008, for what it's worth). The only issue was changing the signing to run from the project properties instead of using an assembly attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice that Media Player on Win7 doesn't have a desk band. Instead it has tiny play/pause buttons in the thumbnail preview that appears when you mouse over the taskbar icon. You can do the same thing for your application. If you use Code Pack (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) there is a sample under Samples\Shell\ThumbnailToolbarDemo. Windows 7 only, but way less annoying than taking up an inch or two of taskbar, and just as handy when you want to insta-pause.