# How to develop a App that embeds into Taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf

I am fairly new to windows programming world. I want to develop a windows application that is embedded into TaskBar(near to system tray) and clicking that actual application should launch. Is C# & WPF are right tools for that or should i use any other programming language. Any thoughts on how it can be done is very appreciated.

Comment: Try to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327457/how-do-i-create-a-toolbar-for-the-taskbar-on-windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can search for "tray bar application c#" or "notifyicon application c#", there are many examples. Also here is a possible duplicate of the question

[How can I make a .NET Windows Forms application that only runs in the System Tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/writing-a-windows-system-tray-application-with-net)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not looking for System Tray application. I want to embed it into the taskbar itself just before System tray area.

Comment: ok , then you should search for "pinning application to taskbar" I guess. Here is a vb version of doing it programatically : http://wayneye.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/programmatically-pin-shortcut-onto-taskbar-on-win7/

Comment: Pinning the application doesn't solve my purpose as it becomes visible after start icon. But I want the application to visible at the other end of taskbar(near to system tray area). I am marking question as answered as I figured out that, the way I thinking to have it is not possible.

Comment: The thing you want is possible. here is a sample code explained:http://www.mstecharticles.com/2012/01/c-implementing-systemtray-using.html.  this is just one example. The basic idea is to use notifyicon control in .net. If you search for it you can find many different examples.